# Какие есть варианты, чтобы не использовать "@" (массивы, for)?

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); // - Обязательно
```

Есть числовой массив c чётным кол-вом ключей (а сколько их вообще - не известно заранее):

```
$arr = ['0'=>'value1', '1'=>'value2', '2'=>'value3', '3'=>'value4'];
```

Стоит задача получить:

```
Array ( [value1] => value2 [value3] => value4 )
```

Делаю так:

```
$count = count($arr);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
   $res[$arr[$i]] = $arr[++$i];
}
```

И всё вроде ок, но когда массив с нечётным кол-вом ключей:

```
$arr = ['0'=>'value1', '1'=>'value2', '2'=>'value3'];
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы получить массив вида:

```
Array ( [value1] => value2 [value3] => )
```

И здесь в `'value3'=>''` — не пропущенна `2`, а именно должен быть `null`

Делаю аналогично, только добавляю костыль в виде `@`:

```
$count = count($arr);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
   @$res[$arr[$i]] = $arr[++$i];
}
```

А без `@` будет выведена ошибка:

> Notice: Undefined offset...

Результат получаю тот, что и нужно:

```
Array ( [value1] => value2 [value3] => )
```

Вот только использование `@` — меня сильно смущает. Как можно этого избежать?

Comment: Изменять индекс цикла for плохая практика, которая влияет на производительность. Проверьте конструкцией if (!isset($arr[$i+1])) наличие существования следующего элемента.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if( count($arr) % 2) array_push( $arr, null);
```

И у вас гарантированно чётное число элементов в массиве – бейте на пары.

Если число элементов массива нечётное, остаток от деления на 2 не ноль, в конец массива дописываем `null`, который достанется последнему ключу, как вы и хотели.

```
if(( $count = count($arr)) % 2) array_push( $arr, null);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i+=2) {
   $res[$arr[$i]] = $arr[$i+1];
}
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/lVw7k5).

Comment: Точно! :) Спасибо @Sergiks :)